# Manually place RecyclerView StaggeredGrid items

Tags: android, gridview, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to use the StaggeredGridLayoutManager in a RecyclerView and I want to be able to manually set which columns and rows an adapter item should be using, but the problem is that it's completely dependent on the order in which items are received and it's a bit random in terms of placement, here's what I want to do.[image]

Here's my Adapter:

```
class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.ContactViewHolder>{

    List<PromotionList> list;

    public RecyclerViewAdapter(List<PromotionList> list){
        this.list = list;
    }

    @Override
    public ContactViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.ad_banner, null);

        return new ContactViewHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ContactViewHolder holder, int position) {

        PromotionList listItem = list.get(position);

        Picasso.with(getActivity())
                .load(listItem.getImageURL())
                .into(holder.promo);
        }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return list.size();
    }

    public class ContactViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        @InjectView(R.id.div)
        ImageView promo;

       public ContactViewHolder(View v){
            super(v);
            ButterKnife.inject(this, v);
        }
    }
}
```

Here's my RecyclerView:

```
rv.setHasFixedSize(true);
rv.setLayoutManager(new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(3, StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL));
rv.setAdapter(new RecyclerViewAdapter(list));
```

Answer (score 0):

SGLM supports only 1 span or full span items. We have plans to support arbitrary span sizes. FYI, GridLayoutManager supports this (your example layout seems like a grid rather than a staggered grid).

Comment: That's awesome news, are there any examples on doing this? I'm basically loading images from parse (backend) and adding them to a list adapter. How should I go about this? Thanks for your help and assistance.